# Agrupar registros en rangos de 15 en 15 en SQL Server 2014

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tengo la siguiente tabla:

[image: TABLA1]

Necesito un script que me retorne los datos de la siguiente forma a partir de `FECHA_INGRESO` y `GETDATE()`:

[image: RESULTADO ESPERADO]

Yo puedo obtener la cantidad de registros, pero no tengo ni idea de como obtenerlos agrupados de 15 en 15. Espero me puedan ayudar. Gracias.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Prueba con el siguiente script. A mi me funcionó. Ten en cuenta que "tabla_original" debe ser el nombre de la tabla sobre la que realizas la consulta. El detalle es el nombre de los rangos de dias...hice que comiencen con letras para poder ordenarlos facilmente.

```
    select COUNT(*) as cantidad_registros, rango_dias
    from (
    select case  
        when dias between 0 and 15 then 'a) 0 a 15'
        when dias between 16 and 30 then 'b) 16 a 30'
        when dias between 31 and 45 then 'c) 31 a 45'
        else 'd) mas de 45' end as rango_dias,
        dias
      from (

    select id, titulo, DATEDIFF(day, fecha_ingreso, GETDATE()) as dias
    from tabla_original) res) tabla
    group by rango_dias order by rango_dias;
```

Espero que te pueda ayudar!

Comment: Me ha servido a la perfección. Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Asumiendo que `fecha_ingreso` es un `datetime`, puedes usar la consulta siguiente. La idea es que puedes usar [`datediff`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/ms189794.aspx) para sacar la cantidad de días entre `fecha_ingreso` y `getdate()`. Y luego haces un `group by` usando una expresión `case` para agrupar por rango de días.

```
;with diffCTE as (
  select datediff(day, fecha_ingreso, getdate()) as cantidad_dias
    from tabla1
), rangoCTE as (
  select case when cantidad_dias <= 15 then 1
              when cantidad_dias <= 30 then 2
              when cantidad_dias <= 45 then 3
              else 4 end as rango_id
    from diffCTE
)
select count(*) as cantidad_registros
       case rango_id
         when 1 then '0 a 15'
         when 2 then '16 a 30'
         when 3 then '31 a 45'
         else 'Mayor a 46' end as rango_dias
  from rangoCTE
 group by rango_id
 order by rango_id
```